# Creating Methods to an existing Controller via Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing model that I'd like to add a number of methods to. While I could **manually** add the methods to the controller as well as its corresponding style/script templates  and routes I'd much rather have them done just as I would've when I created the controller in the first place:

```
rails generate ControllerName hello goodbye
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a perfectly valid thing to want to do.  However the general concensus seems to be that it is too trivial hence why there is no option for it.

A couple of things you could do though:

If you are only adding one or two actions to an otherwise complex controller you could generate another dummy controller with just those two actions.  Then copy over the new bits to your existing controller and trash the dummy one.  Something like git is great for keeping a track on what the generator changed here.

Alternatively if you want to add a lot of new actions to a trivial controller you could save off the original files, let the generator overwrite the existing controller and then put back the original bits.

Remember you can always use the `--pretend` option on the generator to see what it would create without actually doing it.  This can be useful especially to see what view files it would create for the actions in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
rails generate controller mycontroller hello goodbye
```

This would generate controller called `mycontroller` with methods `hello` and `goodbye`.

Comment: Yes but keep in mind you're essentially overwriting the existing controller. This might not work if there were already some methods that you'd still want available.